# How to remove empty "padding" in matplotlib barh plot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to remove/reduce the empty top and bottom `padding` space (marked with red squares) in the `matplotlib.pyplot.barh` plot. How can I do it?

Here is an example of my plot:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
import random


values = sorted(tags_dic.values())
labels = sorted(tags_dic, key=tags_dic.get)
bars = plt.barh(range(len(tags_dic)), values, align='center')
plt.yticks(range(len(tags_dic)), labels)
plt.xlabel('Count')
plt.ylabel('POS-tags')
plt.grid(True)
random.shuffle(COLLECTION)
for i in range(len(tags_dic)):
    bars[i].set_color(COLLECTION[i])
    print COLLECTION[i]
plt.show()
```

Random test data:

```
tags_dic = Counter({u'NNP': 521, u'NN': 458, u'IN': 450, u'DT': 415, u'JJ': 268, u'NNS': 244, u'VBD': 144, u'CC': 138, u'RB': 103, u'VBN': 98, u'VBZ': 69, u'VB': 65, u'TO': 64, u'PRP': 57, u'CD': 51, u'VBG': 50, u'VBP': 48, u'PRP$': 26, u'POS': 26, u'WDT': 20, u'WP': 20, u'MD': 19, u'EX': 11, u'WRB': 10, u'JJS': 7, u'RP': 6, u'JJR': 6, u'RBR': 5, u'NNPS': 5, u'FW': 4, u'SYM': 1, u'UH': 1})
```

Comment: Look at `plt.ylim()`

Comment: I was thinking of `plt.ylim(min(values),max(values))`, but I can't test without sample data

Comment: Ok, max number of POS-tags can be 40, min number is 1. But I tried using `ymin=1, ymax=40` and it produced crazy scewed plot. I don't understand what does `ymin` and `ymax` represent. It is not described in the docs either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can control this with [`plt.margins`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.margins). To completely remove the whitespace at the top and bottom, you can set:

```
plt.margins(y=0)
```

---

As an aside, I think you also have an error in your plotting script: you sort the values from your dictionary, but not the keys, so you end up with labels that don't correspond to the value they represent.

I think you can fix this as follows:

```
labels = sorted(tags_dic, key=tags_dic.get)
plt.yticks(range(len(tags_dic)), labels)
```

Comment: oh, slap! you're right, overlooked a serious bug. Edited.

Comment: that may not be the optimum way of doing things, since you have to sort the dictionary twice. there's probably a more efficient way to do it (probably more important if your dictionary was larger than 40 items)

Comment: Yeah, we can do `oddic = OrderedDict(sorted([(k,v) for k,v in tags_dic.items()], key=lambda x: x[1]))` for example.